# How do I make a range of cells behave like a simple multi-line notepad?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet on which I have a range of cells that I need to behave like a simple notepad.  It looks like this (range is inside the red box):

[image]

This sheet will potentially be edited several times after the initial save.

I'm really at a loss. I would like the user to be able to type on a line and for the text to wrap to the next, also to be able to use line feeds to move text blocks down and backspace to move text blocks up, basically a simple notepad.

Using a Word object looks sloppy and will be confusing to my user.  Using an ActiveX textbox doesn't allow the user to add line feeds. Cell merging and wordwrap just introduce tons of other problems.

Does anyone know an elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: How about `Insert Comment`? Right-click a cell, choose *Insert Comment* and fill-in whatever you like.

Comment: What problems do merging and word-wrapping create?

Comment: Why can't you use a text box instead? Why bend cells to do something they weren't designed to do.

Comment: For the record, this is a Word document in disguise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend an ActiveX text box (found under Insert in the Developer tab)

[image: scr]

Comment: the OP kind of tied our hands behind our backs, `Using an ActiveX textbox doesn't allow the user to add line feeds`

Comment: Why not. If `Design Mode` isn't on you can add line feeds by pressing enter. You can set the text programmatically or by user input and it serializes with the workbook.

Comment: is that true for excel 2010?  I upvoted you, I think your idea is good, but I don't know what the OP is doing with this either.

Comment: I wish I know how the ActiveX text box was different from the Excel Text box. For one the Excel one can have the contents overflow outside, vs the ActiveX one can have scrollbars instead.

Comment: that is probably what the issue with the OP is, they are going to "Save As" PDF every time the sheet is used. and if there is a scroller I don't think it will show all the text.

Comment: FWIW, an ActiveX textbox was my solution.  I found that I could do nearly everything I needed with the properties: BackStyle set to transparent (without gridlines on the sheet) makes the control fit seamlessly with the rest of the sheet.  EnterKeyBehavior, TabKeyBehavior, Multiline, WordWrap, all set to True help to make the box act like a notepad.

Answer (score 3):

**Insert > Textbox**

This allows line feeds and easy editing. You may draw the textbox as small or large as you wish.

[image]

Comment: I think I can make either this or the ActiveX textbox work. The catch is that all controls are hidden in the running version of my spreadsheet and it will be exported as .pdf on save.  I also have to add a dynamic footer every time it's opened, to be tacked on to the user's entered text.

Comment: @mistersister, my solution sounds like it is going to be the best option for your application

Comment: If you need help with that dynamic footer, you could ask another Stack Overflow question on how to add the footer. I will try to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using several cells as a notepad, just use one cell and set the formatting on it to Wrap Text like this

[image: Formatting to Wrap Text]

And

[image: Formatting to Wrap Text Part Deux]

and then set the Row Height to Auto Fit on that row, like this

[image: Row Height to Auto Fit]

And then you can leave your header and footer static in whatever cell(s) and the user can type whatever they want into the "note" cell